# How can I take Sum of 3 levels down entity field, which has ICollection relation between them

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have entities like below, which has ICollection relations between them.
How can I take Sum of MakbuzHareketleri entity's IslemTutari field from Police entity?
I think it is necessary to use nested GroupBy, but I couldn't.

```
public class Police 
{
    public override string Kod { get; set; }
    public EvrakTuru EvrakTuru { get; set; } = EvrakTuru.Police;
    public long AcenteId { get; set; }
    public string Aciklama { get; set; }

    public ICollection<AltPolice> AltPoliceler { get; set; }
}

    public class AltPolice 
{
    public override string Kod { get; set; }
    public long PoliceId { get; set; }
    public PoliceTuru PoliceTuru { get; set; } = PoliceTuru.Police;
    public decimal Prim { get; set; }
    public string Aciklama { get; set; }

    public Police Police { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OdemeBilgileri> OdemeBilgileri { get; set; }
}

    public class OdemeBilgileri
{
    public long AltPoliceId { get; set; }
    public long OdemeTuruId { get; set; }
    public BorcTipi BorcTipi { get; set; } = BorcTipi.MusteriBorcu;
    public DateTime GirisTarihi { get; set; }
    public DateTime Vade { get; set; }        
    public decimal Tutar { get; set; }
    public string Aciklama { get; set; }

    public AltPolice AltPolice { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MakbuzHareketleri> MakbuzHareketleri { get; set; }
}

    public class MakbuzHareketleri
{
    public long MakbuzId { get; set; }
    public int OdemeBilgileriId { get; set; }
    public decimal IslemOncesiTutar { get; set; }
    public decimal IslemTutari { get; set; }
    public DateTime Vade { get; set; }
    public BelgeDurumu BelgeDurumu { get; set; }

    public OdemeBilgileri OdemeBilgileri { get; set; }
}
```

I can do this in Access as follows:

```
SELECT Police.PoliceNo, AltPolice.PoliceId, Sum(MakbuzHareketleri.IslemTutari) AS ToplaIslemTutari
FROM Police INNER JOIN ((AltPolice INNER JOIN OdemeBilgileri ON AltPolice.Id = OdemeBilgileri.AltPoliceId) 
INNER JOIN MakbuzHareketleri ON OdemeBilgileri.Id = MakbuzHareketleri.OdemeBilgileriId) ON Police.Id = AltPolice.PoliceId
WHERE (((OdemeBilgileri.BorcTipi)=1))
GROUP BY Police.PoliceNo, AltPolice.PoliceId, MakbuzHareketleri.BelgeDurumu
HAVING (((MakbuzHareketleri.BelgeDurumu)=2 Or (MakbuzHareketleri.BelgeDurumu)=3));
```

[image: desing]

Answer (score 0):

You should start from the `MakbuzHareketleri` collection and in order to group by multiple columns you should use an anonymous object and for the having clause you should filter the result selection

```
var result = context.MakbuzHareketleri.Where(r=> r.OdemeBilgileri.BorcTipi == 1)
       .GroupBy(r=> new {r.OdemeBilgileri.AltPolice.PoliceId,r.OdemeBilgileri.AltPolice.Police.PoliceNo,r.BelgeDurumu})
        .Select(r=> new {
                     r.Key.PoliceNo,
                     r.Key.PoliceId,
                     ToplaIslemTutari = r.Where(q=> q.BelgeDurumu == 2 || q.BelgeDurumu == 3)
                                         .Select(r=> r.IslemTutari).Sum()
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you, Eldar.  I added comment to my question. Could you please read it.

Comment: Thank you, Eldar,
As far as I see it is not possible to start from top, so from Police entity.
I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

I list my Police entities in my PoliceBll class like below:
How can I adapt your example here to take Sum of MakbuzHareketleri's IslemTutari field?

```
public override IEnumerable<BaseEntity> List(Expression<Func<Police, bool>> filter)
        {
            return BaseList(filter, x => new PoliceL
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                Kod = x.Kod,
                EvrakTuru = x.EvrakTuru,
                AcenteAdi = x.Acente.Adi,
                SigortaTuruAdi = x.SigortaTuru.SigortaTuruAdi,
                PoliceNo = x.PoliceNo,
                RuhsatSahibiId = x.RuhsatSahibiId,
                RuhsatSahibiAdi = x.RuhsatSahibi.CariAdi,
                Plaka = x.Plaka,
                PolicePrimTutari = x.AltPoliceler.Where(y => y.PoliceId == x.Id && y.PoliceTuru == (x.EvrakTuru == EvrakTuru.Police ? PoliceTuru.Police : PoliceTuru.Tecdit)).Select(y => y.Prim).FirstOrDefault(),
                ToplamPrimTutari = x.AltPoliceler.Select(y => y.Prim).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum(),
                Aciklama = x.Aciklama,                
                FirmaId = x.AltPoliceler.Where(y => y.PoliceId == x.Id && y.PoliceTuru == PoliceTuru.Police).Select(y => y.FirmaId).FirstOrDefault(),
                FirmaAdi = x.AltPoliceler.Where(y => y.PoliceId == x.Id && y.PoliceTuru == PoliceTuru.Police).Select(y => y.Firma.FirmaAdi).FirstOrDefault(),
                EklemeTarihi = x.EklemeTarihi,
                EkleyenId = x.EkleyenId,
                EkleyenAdi = x.Ekleyen.Adi,
                DuzenlemeTarihi = x.DuzenlemeTarihi,
                DuzenleyenId = x.DuzenleyenId,
                DuzenleyenAdi = x.Duzenleyen.Adi,
                AltPoliceVar = x.AltPoliceler.Any()
            }).OrderBy(x => x.Kod).ToList();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when I revised the codes like below. So my problem was solved. Thank you for your help.

```
    public override IEnumerable<BaseEntity> List(Expression<Func<Police, bool>> filter)
    {
        return BaseList(filter, x => new
        {

            PoliceBilgisi = x,
            OdemeBilgileriMusteri = x.AltPoliceler.SelectMany(y => y.OdemeBilgileri.Where(z => z.BorcTipi == BorcTipi.MusteriBorcu)),
        }).Select(a => new
        {
            PoliceBilgi = a.PoliceBilgisi,
            MusteridenTahsil = a.OdemeBilgileriMusteri.SelectMany(b => b.MakbuzHareketleri).Where(b =>
            b.BelgeDurumu == BelgeDurumu.HesaptaBeklemede ||
            b.BelgeDurumu == BelgeDurumu.TahsilKasa ||
            b.BelgeDurumu == BelgeDurumu.TahsilBanka ||
            b.BelgeDurumu == BelgeDurumu.AvukatYoluylaTahsil ||
            b.BelgeDurumu == BelgeDurumu.BMosnTahsil ||
            b.BelgeDurumu == BelgeDurumu.KismiTahsilEdildi ||
            b.BelgeDurumu == BelgeDurumu.KismiAvukatYoluylaTahsil ||
            b.BelgeDurumu == BelgeDurumu.KKPosTahsil)
            .Select(b => b.IslemTutari).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum(),
        })
            .Select(x => new PoliceL
            {
                Id = x.PoliceBilgi.Id,
                Kod = x.PoliceBilgi.Kod,
                EvrakTuru = x.PoliceBilgi.EvrakTuru,
                AcenteAdi = x.PoliceBilgi.Acente.Adi,
                SigortaTuruAdi = x.PoliceBilgi.SigortaTuru.SigortaTuruAdi,
                PoliceNo = x.PoliceBilgi.PoliceNo,
                RuhsatSahibiId = x.PoliceBilgi.RuhsatSahibiId,
                RuhsatSahibiAdi = x.PoliceBilgi.RuhsatSahibi.CariAdi,
                Plaka = x.PoliceBilgi.Plaka,
                PolicePrimTutari = x.PoliceBilgi.AltPoliceler.Where(y => y.PoliceId == x.PoliceBilgi.Id && y.PoliceTuru == (x.PoliceBilgi.EvrakTuru == EvrakTuru.Police ? PoliceTuru.Police : PoliceTuru.Tecdit)).Select(y => y.Prim).FirstOrDefault(),
                ToplamPrimTutari = x.PoliceBilgi.AltPoliceler.Select(y => y.Prim).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum(),
                Aciklama = x.PoliceBilgi.Aciklama,
                FirmaId = x.PoliceBilgi.AltPoliceler.Where(y => y.PoliceId == x.PoliceBilgi.Id && y.PoliceTuru == PoliceTuru.Police).Select(y => y.FirmaId).FirstOrDefault(),
                FirmaAdi = x.PoliceBilgi.AltPoliceler.Where(y => y.PoliceId == x.PoliceBilgi.Id && y.PoliceTuru == PoliceTuru.Police).Select(y => y.Firma.FirmaAdi).FirstOrDefault(),
                EklemeTarihi = x.PoliceBilgi.EklemeTarihi,
                EkleyenId = x.PoliceBilgi.EkleyenId,
                EkleyenAdi = x.PoliceBilgi.Ekleyen.Adi,
                DuzenlemeTarihi = x.PoliceBilgi.DuzenlemeTarihi,
                DuzenleyenId = x.PoliceBilgi.DuzenleyenId,
                DuzenleyenAdi = x.PoliceBilgi.Duzenleyen.Adi,
                AltPoliceVar = x.PoliceBilgi.AltPoliceler.Any(),
                MusteridenTahsil = x.MusteridenTahsil,
            }).OrderBy(x => x.Kod).ToList();
    }
```